# knn classification 10 fold implement and sorting

Tags: matlab, classification, knn

i have 8 feature from a mat file 
each of this feature divided 4 part (X_train , Y_train , X_test,Y_test)
for 10 times randomly obtained this parameter
now i should classify this feature according KNN 
my code is here

```
    kk=7;
            bb=1;
         mdl1= ClassificationKNN.fit([X1_train{bb};X2_train{bb};X3_train{bb};X4_train{bb};X5_train{bb};X6_train{bb};X7_train{bb};X8_train{bb};X9_train{bb};X10_train{bb};X11_train{bb};X12_train{bb}],[Y1_train{bb};Y2_train{bb};Y3_train{bb};Y4_train{bb};Y5_train{bb};Y6_train{bb};Y7_train{bb};Y8_train{bb};Y9_train{bb};Y10_train{bb};Y11_train{bb};Y12_train{bb}],'NumNeighbors',kk);
.
.
.
bb=10;
            mdl10= ClassificationKNN.fit([X1_train{bb};X2_train{bb};X3_train{bb};X4_train{bb};X5_train{bb};X6_train{bb};X7_train{bb};X8_train{bb};X9_train{bb};X10_train{bb};X11_train{bb};X12_train{bb}],[Y1_train{bb};Y2_train{bb};Y3_train{bb};Y4_train{bb};Y5_train{bb};Y6_train{bb};Y7_train{bb};Y8_train{bb};Y9_train{bb};Y10_train{bb};Y11_train{bb};Y12_train{bb}],'NumNeighbors',kk);
```

as you seen this functions repeat 10 times for evaluate the 10 mdl
in the following i write this code to simplify the project

```
for j=1:10
    for h=1:12
mdl{j}{h}=ClassificationKNN.fit([X_train{j}{h}],[Y_train{j}{h}]);
    end
end
```

this code work proerly without (mdl{j}{h}) but if this sentence is used i have this error message ((Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object))
anybode know what shall i do to fix this problem
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first you should define the mdl variable size

```
mdll= cell(10, 8);
```

then form this for loop

```
for j=1:10
     mdll{j}= ClassificationKNN.fit([X_train{j}{1};X_train{j}{2};X_train{j}{3};X_train{j}{4};X_train{j}{5};X_train{j}{6};X_train{j}{7};X_train{j}{8};X_train{j}{9};X_train{j}{10};X_train{j}{11};X_train{j}{12}],[Y_train{j}{1};Y_train{j}{2};Y_train{j}{3};Y_train{j}{4};Y_train{j}{5};Y_train{j}{6};Y_train{j}{7};Y_train{j}{8};Y_train{j}{9};Y_train{j}{10};Y_train{j}{11};Y_train{j}{12}],'NumNeighbors',kk);
end
```

i checked it and work correctly